# Selenium não consegue encontrar por id

Tags: java, testes, selenium-webdriver

Estou rodando um teste com o testNG junto com o Selenium

```
org.openqa.selenium.By
```

Teste, fazer essa busca:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("idRoleCheck:0")).click();
```

Dá o seguinte erro:

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

Analisado com a ferramenta para desenvolvimento do Chrome, tem o Id, consigo ver ele, porém acho que é problema desse caractere **":"** , mas não sei, já tentei varias buscas por aqui e outros lugares e nada.

Estou usando o driver:

```
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
```

Alguém já passou por isso?

HTML gerado no browser:

```
<div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">
    <input id="idRoleCheck:0" name="idRoleCheck" value="value"
     onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;idRoleCheck&quot;,e:&quot;change&quot;,p:&quot;idRoleCheck&quot;,u:&quot;idRoleCheck&quot;});" 
    type="checkbox">
</div>
```

Nenhuma das resposta, até o momento resolveu.
Porém evoluirmos conseguimos fazer passar o teste.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@id='idRoleCheck']/tbody/tr/td/div/div[2]/span")).click();
```

O problema **em ler o id** da forma questionada continua, talvez esteja faltando alguma dependência que esta gerando o problema, porque o log, nunca vem com muita informação (ou é assim mesmo).

Usando:

- Selenium 3.0.0-beta2
- ChromeDriver 2.24
- Baixado daqui [Driver Chrome 2.24](http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.24/)

Como se constatou o problema

Usando:

- Selenium IDE (aquele plugin do firefox para gravar os dados do teste)
- Exportado para o tipo (TestNG / Java /WebDriver)
- Ele gera duas linhas, a primeira que da o erro (idRoleCheck:0)
- A segunda lendo pelo **By.xpath(...**

Comment: Cara,
Eu só usei Selenium com Python mas, tu já tentou usar pra pegar com xpath ao invés de id? Ou tem que ser por ID msm?
Eu acho que o xpath é mais confiável, é mais certinho sabe?
Já que tu ta tentando pelo ID e não tá rolando, talvez pelo xpath dê certo!

Answer (score 1):

Tive um problema  parecido e consegui resolver com a seguinte função

Tenta da seguinte forma:

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
```

`js.executeScript(
                "setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('idRoleCheck:0').value = 'value'; }, 1000)");`

se em algum lugar tiver um data-bind referenciado para esse id, use da seguinte forma:

```
js.executeScript(
            "setTimeout(function(){ model."o que tiver dentro do seudata-bin"('o valor que você quer selecionar'); document.getElementById('idRoleCheck:0').value = 'value'; }, 1000)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Tenta colocar duas barras invertidas antes do :, assim:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("idRoleCheck\\:0")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Já tive muitos problemas desse tipo, principalmente com o IE. Você pode tentar encontrar o elemento pelo atributo.

```
By.cssSelector("input[id=idRoleCheck:0]");
```

Comment: Mas eu não sei, o link também, veja é input, do tipo **type="checkbox"**
Tem alguma sugestão de qual seria o link para esse caso?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, isso deve resolver.

Answer (score 0):

Porque você não busca todos os elementos do tipo `checkbox` e depois dar o click no elemento que deseja, é sempre a maneira mais fácil.

**Tipo assim:**

```
List<WebElement> checkboxes = 
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("input[type*=\"checkbox\"]"));
checkboxes.get(0).click();
```